# loop on a group concat on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to see if this is possible.

I have three columns (NAME, TYPE, RATING).

I am trying to see if I can do a group_concat and layout the cells such as this.

TABLE EXAMPLE

```
|   NAME      |  TYPE | RATING   | user_id
-------------  ------ ---------- ---------
 Hello World1  | Text1 | Star1    | 1
 Hello World1  | Text1 | Star1    | 1
 Hello World2  | Text2 | Star2    | 2
 Hello World2  | Text2 | Star2    | 2
 Hello World2  | Text2 | Star2    | 2
 Hello World3  | Text3 | Star3    | 3
 Hello World3  | Text3 | Star3    | 3
 Hello World4  | Text4 | Star4    | 4
 Hello World4  | Text4 | Star4    | 4
```

I want to layout the results like this, where is all grouped in one row, group the user_id

**EXAMPLE A**
ONE ROW

```
NAME: Hello World1, TYPE: Text1, RATING: Star1, 
NAME: Hello World1, TYPE: Text1, RATING: Star1,
NAME: Hello World2, TYPE: Text2, RATING: Star2,
NAME: Hello World2, TYPE: Text2, RATING: Star2,
NAME: Hello World2, TYPE: Text2, RATING: Star2,
NAME: Hello World3, TYPE: Text3, RATING: Star3,
NAME: Hello World3, TYPE: Text3, RATING: Star3,
NAME: Hello World4, TYPE: Text4, RATING: Star4,
NAME: Hello World4, TYPE: Text4, RATING: Star4
```

I know if I do this:

```
 concat('NAME: ',group_concat(name separator ' : '),
             ' TYPE: ',group_concat(type separator ' : '),
             ' RATING: ',group_concat(rating separator ' : ')
           ),
```

I'll get this.

**EXAMPLE B**

```
NAME: Hello World, Hello World, Hello World, Hello World, Hello World
TYPE: Text, Text,Text,Text,Text,
RATING: Star,Star,Star,Star,Star,
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish EXAMPLE A? There are also user_ids that are the same so I am trying to group them all into one row for an import.

Comment: That's not three tables, it's one table with three columns.

Comment: @Barmar, whoops, type-O, I meant three columns.

Comment: You need a simple field concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the columns in a single `GROUP_CONCAT()`, don't nest them inside `CONCAT()`. This will concatenate all the values from the same row, and then concatenate all of them by `user_id`.

Use `SEPARATOR '\n'` to put each element on a new line.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('NAME: ', name, ', TYPE: ', type, ', RATING: ', rating SEPARATOR ',\n')
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I do have multiple rows in a group, grouping by a user_id.  Thats why I was using grou_concat

Comment: Please update the question. Show multiple user IDs in the input, and how you want each one to be grouped in the result.

Comment: Done, I updated the question with the user_id

Comment: Where is the user ID grouping in the result?

Comment: It would help if you didn't have identical values in every row, so we could see how the output is related to the inputs.

Comment: gotcha, ok, i updated my output.  let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: How is that different from my result? It looks like you just inserted a blank line between each user ID, you're not grouping into a single row. Do that in your application program.

Comment: its not grouped by user_id (creates multiple rows concatenate), trying to see if i can group all user_id = 1 (etc) into one row.   in that format.

Comment: Your sample output doesn't have all the results for the same user_id on the same row.

Comment: Yes, this is it, I appreciate it.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Separator should be comma newline